# Django object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an object that I'm trying to iterate over within my template.

My issue is that one of the fields **response** contains **json** data and I get this error message:

> **transaction' object is not iterable**

```
{% for item in transaction %}
    {{ item.notjson_fields}}
     
    {% for jsonItem in item.response %} 

       {{jsonItem}}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

**Model:**

```
 date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 request = JSONField()
 response = JSONField()
```

Comment: I assumed this was the error yes.

Comment: What is `transaction`?

Comment: @Ngenator nothing shows. and transaction is a  transaction = get_object_or_404(Transaction, vendor_tx_id=id) one field has json data tho in the db

Comment: values = list(values). whih means ``Transaction`` is not an iterable object like list, dict. There should be a method/property(attributet) that you are looking for from transaction. if ``get_object...`` is what you are using, it should return an instance of the db record that matches ur query.

Comment: Is Transaction a ManyToMany relationship? Can you post the definition of Transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over a `Transaction` object which is not iterable.

Try something like

```
{{ transaction.notjson_fields}}

{% for jsonItem in transaction.response %} 
    {{ jsonItem }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can't be sure though without knowing what `Transaction` looks like

---

Edit:

Since response is a JSONField, you can access it like a dict. Just do

```
{{ transaction.response.amount }}
```

Comment: ok thats seems to work but how do i get the value {{ jsonItem.amount }} is blank where {{ jsonItem }} is all the fields

Comment: It may be a string then. Do you deserialize it at all? How is it stored in the database?

Comment: response is a direct store of a json request I get ie. in the db it looks like this {"VendorTxCode": "k34m73cr3rhrnghuhsw5drfg7y" etc..}

Comment: What is the field type? Are you using something like https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield or https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field? If not you need to deserialize the data into an object in order to access the key/value pairs.

Comment: its a JSONField() in the model

Comment: So then you should do `{{ transaction.response.amount }}`

Comment: {{ transaction.response.amount }} does not give a value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28843/discussion-between-ngenator-and-user7)

Answer (score 1):

If like Ngenator said, your field is not a JSON object but a string, you may need to load it first. First register a new template tag

```
    from django import template
    register = template.Library()
    import json

    @register.filter
    def load_json(value):
        return json.loads(value)
```

Then to get (just) the amount in your template

```
    {% with transaction.response|load_json as jsondict %}
    {% for k, v in jsondict.items %}
        {% if k == "amount" %}
            <td>{{ v }}</td>
        {% endif %}   
    {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: you sure is not json as the field in the db is  JSONField()?

Comment: That may depend on how you pass it from views to template. Try looping the transaction.response in your template and see what you get.

Comment: I get a list of fields but not the values

Comment: Does {{ jsonItem.VendorTxCode }} have value?